# How can i encode a sentence in C# [Cryptography]

Tags: c#, cryptography

I am currently working on an exercise where I am supposed to create two functions. One for encoding a sentence. And the second one for decoding another sentence. It's like cryptography.

Functions apart, I'm trying to program the code as a simple way.

Here are the steps:

1. Reading what user is typing.
2. Compare the string recieved with an alphabet.
3. when the letter is similar, the cryptography's command's acting (letter moves forward 8 steps).

Example:

```
String Alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
Console.WriteLine("Indiquez votre phrase à encoder:");
string PhraseAEncoder = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine(PhraseAEncoder);
int PositionLettreFinale = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < Alphabet.Length; i++)
{
    if (PhraseAEncoder[i] == Alphabet[i])
    {
        PositionLettreFinale = Alphabet[i + 8]; // Je récupère la position finale.
        Console.WriteLine(PositionLettreFinale);
    }
    while (i != PositionLettreFinale)
    {
        i++;
        Console.WriteLine(Alphabet[i]);
    }
}
```

It is written in French. But I think you could get it.

Problem: My for is infinite, I can't get a single result.

Comment: Have you tried single-stepping through the code in the debugger?

Comment: Please compare the Console.WriteLine and Console.Write methods.

Comment: No, i will check the debugger. Plus, yesterday i succes for a single character. But as a string, this code doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I see two main issues in your code:

`PositionLettreFinale = Alphabet[i + 8];`

1. Here you can get outside of `Alphabet` array (For example when `i` equals to 24, you will access element in 32nd position and it doesn't exist). [IndexOutOfRangeException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.indexoutofrangeexception(v=vs.110).aspx)
2. Also in the same line, you are assigning a value of type `char` to the variable `PositionLettreFinale` type of `int`.

When assigning a value of type `char` to a variable of type `int`, it will be converted to `int` based on [ASCII Table](https://www.dotnetperls.com/ascii-table).

And now, an answer to your question.

> Problem: My for is infinite, I can't get a single result.

`for` isn't infinite, `while` is infinite.

`while (i != PositionLettreFinale)`

You are comparing `i` with a decimal value of `char`. They will never be equal because of  `i` has maximal value  25 (`Alphabet.Length - 1`) and  `PositionLettreFinale`  has minimal value 'a' (97).

Answer (score 0):

The code can not work. Simple "crypto" method example: *(based on your code)*

```
private static string Crypto(string PhraseAEncoder, int shift)
{
  string Alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
  StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(PhraseAEncoder.Length);
  foreach (char c in PhraseAEncoder)
  {
    int code = Alphabet.IndexOf(c);
    if (code < 0)
      result.Append(c);
    else
    {
      code += shift;
      if (code >= Alphabet.Length)
        code %= Alphabet.Length;
      else
      {
        while (code < 0)
          code += Alphabet.Length;
      }
      result.Append(Alphabet[code]);
    }
  }
  return result.ToString();
}
```

And usage:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Indiquez votre phrase à encoder:");
  string PhraseAEncoder = Console.ReadLine().ToLower(); // alphabet is only in lowercase
  string result = Crypto(PhraseAEncoder, 8); // crypto password "8"
  Console.WriteLine(result);
  result = Crypto(result, -8);  // crypto reverse password "-8"
  Console.WriteLine(result);
  if (string.Equals(result, PhraseAEncoder))
    Console.WriteLine("OK");
  else
    Console.WriteLine("Error");
}
```